# How can I use multiple jwt authentication for laravel 10?

Tags: laravel

I have created two guards.Admin and Manager. To create authentication for admin I have followed https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-jwt/ this blog and it worked well. For my 2nd guard authentication middleware route manager not working. It says Manager not found.So I put only admin in group route and for manager I have declared the guard inside of auth method but It still not working. It can't find my model to store so I had to post the row data inside phpmyadmin manually and checked the login if it works or not but it's still not working. Returns the error part.

**Api.php**

```
Route::post('/manager/register', [App\Http\Controllers\ManagerUserController::class,'register']);
    Route::post('/manager/login', [App\Http\Controllers\ManagerUserController::class,'authenticate']);
    Route::get('open', [ManagerDataController::class,'open']);

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function() {
        Route::get('user', [ManagerUserController::class,'getAuthenticatedUser']);
        Route::get('closed', [ManagerDataController::class,'closed']);
    });
    

Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'],function($router){
    Route::post('/admin/register', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminUserController::class,'register']);
    Route::post('/admin/login', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminUserController::class,'authenticate']);
    Route::get('open', [AdminDataController::class,'open']);

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function() {
        Route::get('user', [AdminUserController::class,'getAuthenticatedUser']);
        Route::get('closed', [AdminDataController::class,'closed']);
    });
```

**managerController:**

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
        {
            $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

            
                if (! $token = auth()->guard('manager')->attempt($credentials)) {
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
                }
            

            return response()->json(compact('token'));
        }
```

**auth.php**

```
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'admin',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'manager' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'managers',
],
]
```

Another problem is if I set web for default guard then admin guard not working but if I put admin as default guard then it works. It this work like this then how can I use multi jwt authentication cause theres only single default guard exists!

Comment: Not clear why you are using two "different" jwt any particular reason

Comment: I don't know how to use two same jwt